# Change activity clicking a list item with slidingmenu

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-menu, navigation-drawer

Right now i insert the slidingmenu in my application! Before it, i had 2 items menu. This two items where (are), two activities. Of course clicking on the corrispondent item i could go in the right activity. Now i have an array in the strings.xml with the items:

```
<string-array name="marray">
   <item>ACTIVITY1</item>
   <item>ACTIVITY2</item>
</string-array>
```

and a layout that calls the items

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:entries="@array/marray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So i have the listview in the navdrawer.. Now, how can i click in the first item and go to my activity? Thanks

EDIT(if needs): 
The MenuFragment.java

```
public class MenuFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    ListView list;
    MenuClickInterFace mClick;

    interface MenuClickInterFace {
        void onListitemClick(String item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mClick = (MenuClickInterFace) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                String i=(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                mClick.onListitemClick(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of your Activity is in the String i, right? Either you take now the manual way:

```
if (i == "A") {
startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class));
}
else if (i == "B") {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, B.class));
}
```

or you choose the "automatically" way:

```
try {
    Intent openNewIntent = new Intent( this, Class.forName(i) );
    startActivity( openNewIntent );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

taken from [How to create Intent using a string to launch another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387139/how-to-create-intent-using-a-string-to-launch-another-activity)

Comment: and if in the future i'll create another one item, is possible use the `case` condition?

Comment: the "automatically" way works for as many items as you want!


if you want to use the "manually" way, `case` condition is the best idea, right